# What means (q) after sha in git log?

Tags: git, logging

What exactly means this `(q)` right after sha number in my git log? I use this shortcut in `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
        lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

And typing `git lol` gives a line: `* 068533d (q)` + short description

Comment: Make sure to also set (globally) the `color.ui` configuration variable to `auto` -- you'll get this output beautifully colored which helps to perceive the information printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it's a branch name. Can you check if you have branch named `q` when you execute `git branch`?

Comment: More strictly, it's the name of a ref which happen to point to that commit, with the ref (Git parlance for "reference") being a branch or a tag. If there's more than one ref pointing at the commit, they will all be listed inside the parentheses.

Comment: True. I found `q` in branch list. Thanks!

Comment: @kostix: yes, you're right, it can be any ref. I'm assuming it's a branch because with tag it would say `(tag: q)`.